# Why for loop failure in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-scope

[image]I am having a angularjs script. In 4th if condition (if(myflag == 2)), when i am enter any minus value less than array length then that time array element removed with same product id. For Example, In my array there are 5 element of same product id, Now i want to remove 4 element then i am entering -4 then my array does not flow 4 time and splice specific index

//SCript

```
$scope.checkEneteredQuantity = function(qty,bagProduct){
  var qty = parseInt(qty);
  var nwqt = parseInt(qty); 
  var myflag = 0;
  if(qty > 0){

    myflag = 1;

  }else if(qty < 0){

    myflag = 2;
  }
  if(myflag == 1){
    for(var i = 0;i < qty ; i++){
        bagProduct.count = 1;
        $scope.addProductInBag(bagProduct);
    }
  }
  if(myflag == 2){
    var nt = Math.abs(nwqt);
    var ct = 0
    for(var k = 0;k < $scope.newBagListOfProduct.length;k++){
      if($scope.newBagListOfProduct[k].prod_id == bagProduct.prod_id){ 
          if(nt != ct){
            bagProduct.count = 1;
            $scope.newBagListOfProduct.splice(k,1);
          }
          ct ++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so as per your question, if i enter -2 it should remote product id 2? and its not working for -4?

Comment: Please chek images

Comment: if there are 4 items in array, it will work till 3, right? since indexing start from 0?